# Use Cakephp Validation with custom form / without formhelper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can I use Cakephp validation without formhelper?

for example, I was created model, controller, and view like this

model:

```
class KnowledgeBase extends AppModel {
   public $useTable = 'corp_kb';

 public $validate = array(
        'kb_title' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '2'), 
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'min 2 char'
        ),
);
}
```

controller:

```
class KnowledgeBaseController extends AppController 
{
var $name = 'KnowledgeBase';
var $ext = '.php';
public $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Js');

function kb_fill()
    {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }

function kb_input()
    {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->KnowledgeBase->set($this->data);
    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
        if($this->KnowledgeBase->validates())
        {
        debug($this->data);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "data empty";
    }
    }
```

view "kb_fill":

```
<form id="kb_frm" method="get" action="" >
<input type="text" name="data[Knowledgebase][kb_title]"/>
<button id="postbutton">Post !</button>
</form>
```

for some reason I used ajax to load post into kb_input via button id, and cannot use usual method. the cakephp validation not working, or not showing the message error
how can I use it without formhelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are halfway there. The method `$this->KnowledgeBase->validates()` in your Controller will only return `true` or `false`. To manually work on the validation errors, you'll need this:

```
if ($this->KnowledgeBase->validates()) {
    // it validated logic
} else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $errors = $this->KnowledgeBase->validationErrors;
}
```

Took the code sample from [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html), I would recommend you to take a look at it, as you may find further information about how to validate your data via Controller.

Comment: It works!! thank you
I just Foreach the $errors and result them

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to show error messages we need to put this error method of form helper.
i.e.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->error('kb_title') ?>
```

If you use cakephp `Formhelper` input method then it will give error messages by default, where as if you use any static html like 
yours then you've to use error method of form helper to display error messages.

```
<form id="kb_frm" method="get" action="" >
<input type="text" name="data[Knowledgebase][kb_title]"/>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('kb_title') ?>
<button id="postbutton">Post !</button>
</form>
```

you can get the validation error of a form using `error` method of `form helper`, if you don't want to use this method then you can have a 
look at on `$validationErrors` Property of view [here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-View.html#%24validationErrors)

so you can get the error message by using `$this->validationErrors['Knowledgebase']['kb_title']`

Comment: let me know if you have any query or concern, glad to help you

Comment: thx for your answer, but in my case.
the insert function is different from the form function
but thx for your suggest