# validation errors not showing in custom form from users model in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
we have created sign up form in html, but validation from model are not showing in form
but if we create form in simple php as given in documentation validation are working.
so how should we add custom validation from users model in signup form.
```

i have tried several solution from stackoverflow but none is working.
   i want to show error message as written in model class in form below inputbox

here is my code

```
 <div id="content">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
   <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
     <div class="container">
        <section>   
            <div id="container_demo" >       
              <div id="wrapper">
                 <div id="login" class="animate form">
             <form  action="/googleAtIntgeration/users/add" autocomplete="on" 
             method="post"> 
          <h1> Sign up </h1> 
         <div class ="flashmsg" ><?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?></div>
         <p> 
      <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Username<span 
        class="required">*</span></label>
       <input id="usernamesignup" name="data[User][username]" required="required" 
          type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
          </p> 
        <p <?php echo $this->Form->error('username') ?></p>
           <p> 
         <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password<span 
        class="required">*</span> </label>
        <input id="password" name="data[User][password]" required="required" 
         type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
          </p>
        <p> <?php echo $this->Form->error('password') ?></p>
        <p> 
      <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Confirm 
       Password<span class="required">*</span> </label>
        <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="data[User][confirm_password]" 
       required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
        </p>
       <p><?php echo $this->Form->error('confirm_password') ?></p>
        <p> 
        <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" >Email<span 
        class="required">*</span></label>
      <input id="emailsignup" name="data[User][email]" required="required" type="email" 
      placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
       </p>
      <p> <?php echo $this->Form->error('email') ?></p>
        <p>
       <div class="input select"><label for="country">Country</label>
     <select name="data[User][country]" class="inputbox" id="country"><option 
      value="">Select Country</option>
      <?php echo $this->User->countryDropDown() ?>
     </select>
     </div>
      </p>
      <p class="signin button"> 
       <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/></p>
       <p class="change_link"> 
        Already a member ?
<a href="/googleAtIntgeration/users/login" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
        </p>
<input name="activity_code" type="hidden" value="REG"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>  
        </section>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>   
     </div>
```

so please suggest some solution.
     $errors = $this->User->validationErrors; added in controller.

Comment: Can you please give us some code you have tried?...

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the errors in the view file.

Try adding the following in your controller:

```
<?php
    $errors = $this->User->validationErrors;
    $this->set('errors', $errors);
?>
```

Try adding the following just after the body tag in your View file, the one that ends in .ctp:

```
<?php debug($errors); ?>
```

This should give you an understanding of how it works.

Also, try referring to the following Question/answer:

[Use Cakephp Validation with custom form / without formhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042559/use-cakephp-validation-with-custom-form-without-formhelper)

I strongly suggest you stop manipulating CakePHP, and doing it "the CakePHP way" use form helpers there's a reason they are there. At first they're daunting to use and don't make sense, but once you learn how to use them, you'll find them time saving....

Comment: thanks problem solved ... html form was not working in cakephp so i used and make form with the help of php as given in cakephp documentation